# Add @ transactional annotation to the method in spring. Is the transaction submitted after or before the end of the method?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

When learning to use the 'reentrant lock' lock today, I encountered a problem. Add the lock to the code of the sold goods business.

```java
@Service
public class ServiceOne{
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    public Result  func(long seckillId, long userId) {
        lock.lock();
        // Check stock
        // sale
        // Reduce stock
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The premise is to use the re-read isolation mechanism of the MySQL database. In the case of high concurrency, suppose that there are multiple threads calling the method at the same time. When the transaction can be opened and submitted completely between 'lock' and 'unlock', there will be no oversold problem.

Obviously, the transaction must be started after 'lock', so the key is whether the transaction must be submitted before 'unlock'.
If it is after 'unlock', then it is really possible to oversell: for example, when thread 1 finishes executing the method, but the transaction has not yet been committed, thread 2 obtains the lock and starts to execute the method. Under the 'repeatable read' isolation mechanism, thread 2 can not read the operation results of thread 1 pair of stores, thus oversold.

I hope you can come to answer your questions! be deeply grateful!

Comment: `@Transactional` is implemented as "around" advice.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the transaction submitted after or before the end of the method?

Your method is not only what actually is executed by Spring. Spring uses proxies, so as you can quess for your class and for your method a proxy is created as well.

As already commented `@Transactional` is implemented using the aspect `around` meaning some code before your method's execution and some code after your method's execution is executed as well.

So if you have written

```
@Transactional
public void method1 () {

    doSomething1;
    doSomething2;

}
```

What the proxy of spring may actually seem like will be

```
 public void method1 () {

        /*
          Extra code from spring to open a transaction.
        /*
    
        doSomething1;
        doSomething2;

        /*
          Extra code from spring to close a transaction.
        /*
    }
```

**Short answer:** Transaction will be closed after all statements of the method which you have written are executed.

- If your method finishes with throwing an unchecked exception then a rollback will be invoked.
- If your method finishes throwing a checked exception or a return statement or void if nothing is declared to be returned then a commit will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

@Transactional is used to make that operation atomic. Means the unlock is executed at the end of the method.